# Некорректное отображение DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Создала приложение которое добавляет строчки в DataGridView по событиям одновременно задается раскраска.

Мне необходимо чтобы приложение располагалось внизу экрана на уровне панели задач.

Но как только задать свойство формы location: 10, 900 (~800) DataGridView отображается неверно, отрисовка неверная, строки черные, пропадают отображения кнопок.

Если курсором водить по форме (щелкать) кнопки, строчки и цвет строчек появляется.

С чем это может быть связано?

Функционально всё работает верно.

Сначала разрабатывала на двух мониторах (ноутбук + монитор) работало нормально. Потом не было доступа к отдельному монитору, открыла только на ноутбуке. С тех пор перестало корректно отображаться.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Ошибка была в драйверах AccessDatabaseEngine

Comment: А что если попробовать Refresh()? Если после наведения мыши всё приходит в норму, то должно помочь.

Comment: Так зачем хардкодить позицию? Понятное дело, что на разных экранах вы получите разное отображение. Считайте ее как высота экрана минус высота формы хотя бы.

Comment: Сделала как вы советовали, но не помогло. Нашла строчку где форма меняет своё положение и неверно отображает GridView. Это подключение к бд Access. Без бд работает и отображается корректно.